# How to store signatures in a pda and invoke an instruction with signatures

Tags: pda, signature, instruction

I want to create a program influenced by multisig structure. 
There will be multiple types of instructions that require two parties to sign each transaction. Here's what I have in my mind:

- There will be a pda account that stores the signatures of both parties
- An execution instruction then will require this pda and an instruction
- This instruction will invoke the instruction with the signatures inside the pda

Is it possible to create such a structure? The reason why I want to implement this structure is to create a request program, where both parties need to sign to execute a instruction inside the program, but I don't want two signers in the instruction itself. Instead, I want each user to be able to sign each instruction independently and system will execute the instruction if both parties have signed the instruction.

Comment: Signatures are only valid for max 2 minutes once they were created because what they sign includes a blockhash that can be max 2 minutes old. Maybe check `durable nonces`, I suspect these are what you're looking for.

Comment: After a quick glance, this seems like what I needed. But I'll still explore and reply back after I completely figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you don't need to store any signatures in your program.

Multisig participants sign a transaction that includes an instruction to your program. Your program checks that the multisig participant signed, and simply flips a bit saying "participant X has approved this instruction". Once enough participant bits have been flipped, then your multisig program can issue the instruction with a "signature" from the PDA.

The full signature is useless to your program, it simply needs to know that the person signed.